# onVerticalDragUpdate and onPanUpdate of GestureDetector does not get called with a ListView as child of GestureDetector Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, gesturedetector

I want to develop an app where I use a `TabBar` that consists of two screens. In the first screen, I have a `ListView`. I want the `TabBar` to be hidden when the `ListView` is scrolled down, and to be shown back when the `ListView` is scrolled up. I used `GestureDetector` as the parent of `ListView` to detect that the user scrolled up and/or down. By searching online, I found that using `onVerticalDragUpdate` and `onPanUpdate` can detect up and down vertical scroll. But now the problem is that these methods are not called! Other methods of `GestureDetector` such as `onTap` are called. I think the reason is that the `ListView` absorbs the vertical scroll. So what is the solution for this? Your help is strongly appreciated!!

**Note:** Using `SliverAppBar` does not match my requirements well.

Here is my code:

```
SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            TabBarView(
              controller: _controller,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print('onTap called!');
                  },
                  onVerticalDragUpdate: (updates) {
                    print('onVerticalDragUpdate is called!');
                  },
                  onPanUpdate: (update) {
                    print('onPanUpdate is called!');
                  },
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text('Hi there! $index'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(color: Colors.purpleAccent),
              ],
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _controller,
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  insets: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: -8),
                ),
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: const [
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Social',
                    height: 36,
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    icon: Text('Videos'),
                    height: 36,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Although the answer from @Ivan Dermenzhy solved by problem, but I will appreciate other answers with alternative ways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
   onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
       if (scrollNotification is UserScrollNotification) {
           ....
       }
       
       return false;
   },
   child: ... }
```

or choose another type of `ScrollNotification` if `UserScrollNotification` doesn't fit to you

Comment: Thank your for your awesome answer! It really worked for me! I know leaving a comment just for thanking is not good, but this really did my job!